# Self-hosted gallery that will base on existing library structure

Tags: software, web, photo-galleries

I have thousands of photos sorted in hierarchical structure of folders (like Family->John). 
This library is shared between various devices like DLNA (TV), cloud (android), network sharing (samba, webDav) etc...

I'm looking for web-based software that allows me to show my photo library in a web browser.

I already tried Piwigo, Gallery3, Koken and Lychee but they are based on their own proprietary file structure/format and have to synchronize databases.

I need something to be able to add new photos from various locations using different protocols, without importing, synchronizing etc..

What other programs should I check out?

Comment: This might get better results at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let us know if you'll find a solution

Comment: This is not about photography.

Answer (score 2):

After research (checked over 15 galleries) I found [PhotoShow](http://www.photoshow-gallery.com/) that fulfils my requirements and does the job.

The installation as a web application is quite simple. It works without database and needs only path to photos directory. It keeps album and photos structure according to file system hierarchy.
Additionally it allows to create users and grants them privileges.

Unfortunately the latest update was 2 years ago so project is abandoned. 
I found there few minor but annoying bugs that never will be fixed. Potentially security issues as well.

Comment: Ooh, yeah — unmaintained PHP code. I think I'd stay away.

Comment: It looks like PhotoShow was updated in May just after this answer posted. https://github.com/thibaud-rohmer/PhotoShow/releases

Comment: Now in version 3, last commit in July; so possibly not dead yet!